# Simple comet example using php and jquery

Tags: php, http, iis, comet, keep-alive

Can anyone give me a good and simple example of the comet technique using PHP?

I just need an example that uses a persistent HTTP connection or something similar.  I don't want to use a polling technique, because I have something like that set up and not only is it difficult to work with and manage its a big hog of resources. Also I am using IIS7 not Apache.

A good example would be really helpful so I can move on from this ugly polling technique.

Comment: getclicky.com seem to be using polling method quite successfully

Answer (score 15):

You should use polling, or use a web server which is specially conceived for long requests and COMET, with a good JS backend:

```
function listen() {
    $.get("/mylongrequestfile", {}, function(data) {
        $("#mydiv").html(data);
        listen(); // then launch again
    }));
};
```

Remember that COMET is "wait for data, if there's data return and exit", so JS backend will have to parse the data and re-launch the process of asking the server.

In this example, if there is a server side problem or just a disconnection from the user side, the entire process will be broken (the function is only called if the request is successful)

Comment: +1 Great code, would you recommend making this sleep in between requests?

Comment: the server itself should make the `sleep` effect, so the server should wait before giving the response until one of these happens (1- new data found, 2- request timed out)

Answer (score 6):

Check this out: [How to implement COMET with PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start).
This is not using JQuery. It is made using PHP and Prototype. It is very easy to understand. I think you can made JQuery script easily after viewing this.

Answer (score 3):

I have a very simple example here that can get you started with comet. It covers compiling Nginx with the NHPM module and includes code for simple publisher/subscriber roles in jQuery, PHP, and Bash.

http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/2010/08/27/comet-with-nginx-and-jquery/

A working example (simple chat) can be found here:
http://cheetah.jamieisaacs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Never having used this technique and studying the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) on the topic, "Long Polling" seems like the only viable solution. It sounds pretty simple to implement by infinitely looping and sleeping a script on the server. There's some [actual code](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming#Streaming_Wiki_Demo) in the [HTTP Streaming page](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming) linked to from the Wikipedia article.

Have you tried any of this and stumbled on specific problems?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this demo video for implementing Long Polling ( comet )..
It might help you all

http://www.screenr.com/SNH

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this [article](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start), it's a really good start to understand comet programming concepts.

You will find two examples on it. The first one use the iframe technique whereas the second one use a persistent connection.

Answer (score 0):

For IIS, there's [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync). Since you're using PHP, however, you might be better off with [WebSync On-Demand](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync). Either one will give you the server-push you're looking for, and is simple to use. Check out [this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427861/is-there-an-alternative-of-ajax-that-does-not-require-polling-without-sever-side)n as well, which is basically what you're after.

Here's [a simple example of WebSync On-Demand in action](http://www.jerodandangela.com/websync-ondemand.htm) using *no* scripting language. Simply open in two windows, and see the publish/subscribe in action.

To publish from the server, you can use the [PHP api](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/support/documentation/publishers#php).