# How to push an alert or message to web page visitor?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, string, push

I am wondering if this is possible to push a message from server to web browser?? 
Like you want to alert user or any message that you want to send to specific user... An example is as chat invitation is sent from chat operator to site visitor...

Is it possible?? i prefer to use PHP, Javascript

I don't want to use AJAX calls to PULL, i want to PUSH.

Looking forward.

Comment: It's certainly possible. but annoying.

Comment: If you are familiar with Google Web Toolkit, you should look at this link:
[http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ)

Comment: please refer this thread of Stackoverflow     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320542/simple-comet-example-using-php-and-jquery

Answer (score 3):

You can't actually push yet. You can use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) techniques, including [long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling), but you can't actually push yet. Someday you'll be able to use [web sockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/).

Comment: "Someday" well as soon as FX4 and Opera 11 are release, who cares about IE anyways? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to do this is just to use AJAX to pull every so often.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to be running some sort of program on the client that you can push stuff to.

Like

- an IM client or similar program
- a browser window with a page that does frequent Ajax checks (probably the most easy way to go)
- a browser window with a page that has a [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) connection open.