# APE - Ajax Push Engine

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ape

Situation:

There are two users, user1 sends message to user2. I would like to use APE to notify user2 that there's a message from user1.

I've already made to show the notification but both users received the notification. My question will be, What should I do that only user2 will receive the notification?

Is there something I need to change in the channels?

Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need a comet implementation.

Here you can find more information about it.
[Simple comet example using php and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320542/simple-comet-example-using-php-and-jquery)

and here you can find an example that I've already done and works well!
http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start