# Idea how to implement server-push content without php looping

Tags: php, mysql, comet

I was implementing the server-push content using comet to the client browser.
There should be updates when mysql got insert then something will happen to client, so I'm currently doing by PHP like this:

```
PHP
  while (check database if update is there)
  {
    usleep(10000); 
   // do write json
  }
```

It actually working, but what happening to me is my hosting(shared) run out of resource even when I just test with 5 simultaneous clients.
CPU is 40% loading at this moment and cause account disable.

So please someone advise any idea how to trigger php to send out the new update only without looping check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you  have a slight error regarding [`usleep`](http://php.net/manual/function.usleep.php). The parameter should be:

> **micro seconds**
>   Halt time in micro seconds. A micro second is one millionth of a
>   second.

Your script currently halts for 0.01 seconds instead of 10 seconds, which, I assume, is not what you wanted.

---

use:

```
usleep(10 * 1000000);
```

or:

```
sleep(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your Javascript looks like, but I think you're approaching it incorrect. What you really wanna do is probably to send requests from the browser with 10 secs intervals. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320542/simple-comet-example-using-php-and-jquery).

Answer (score 1):

This method will not use any CPU during the sleep time:

```
set_time_limit(0);
while (check database if update is there) {
   sleep(10); 
   // do write json
}
```