# Best way to show notifications and messages LIVE on a webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, comet, websocket

I am interested in a really good way of doing instant messaging like meebo and facebook and myspace all have, also for notifications on a page.  Example on my site now, when a user receives a new mail message, photo comment, profile comment, friend request, some other things, they will receive a notification message and link on the page they are on using jQuery and AJAX.

I believe on a large scale that this is not the best way to do it though as my jquery code will have to basically run a PHP script to query the mysql table every 30 seconds or so for every user who has the page open with this script running.  I would like to eventually add in some sort of instant messaging like facebook has in a chat bar at the bottom of the screen if I can find out an efficient way of doing it.

I have heard the terms Comet and HTML5 WebSockets but I am not sure if these are the solutions I  should be looking at for such a feature?  I would like to keep bandwidth at a minimum and running a query every few seconds does not seem very efficient on a high traffic site.

If you know some good solutions, please explain how they work a little bit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Facebook uses [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) for their chat, so have a look at it.

XMPP is

> an open technology for real-time communication, which powers a wide range of applications including instant messaging, presence, multi-party chat, voice and video calls, collaboration, lightweight middleware, content syndication, and generalized routing of XML data.

You'd install a [separate server](http://xmpp.org/software/servers.shtml) to handle messaging and in your app you'd implement a client with one of the available [libraries](http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml#php).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a "comet" server. Since you're talking PHP, your best solution would be a SaaS solution, such as [WebSync On-Demand](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync), since PHP has issues with scaling when it comes to large numbers of concurrent connections being held open. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427861/is-there-an-alternative-of-ajax-that-does-not-require-polling-without-sever-side).

Answer (score 1):

Could you have a shared message queue that ajax can query? Maybe its a php script that stores a majority of the message in memcached (and possibly write to db in case of failure).

Not sure, but curious to hear other solutions ...

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you need to implement a Comet server (ie implement Server Push). The standard web hosts and apache don't readily allow you to do this easily. Another hosted solution (apart from Web Sync) is [Goldfish Server](http://goldfishserver.com). Currently free.